# smtplib emojis sent to my iphone turn into '????' question marks

Tags: python, text

i've looked up other ways people send emoji's all relating back to adding
.encode(utf-8) which i did @ `email.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, email_message.encode("utf-8"))` , without it it was sending unicode

```
def send_priceChange_via_email(
    number: str,
    message: str,
    sender_credentials:tuple,
    smtp_server:str= server,
    smtp_port: int= port
):

    sender_email, email_token = sender_credentials
    receiver_email = f'{number}{carrier}'
    email_message =  f'To:{receiver_email}\r\n{message}'

    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, smtp_port, context = ssl.create_default_context()) as email:
        email.login(sender_email, email_token)
        email.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, email_message.encode("utf-8"))

def textme(message):
    sender_credentials = (gmail,token)
    send_priceChange_via_email(mobile, message, sender_credentials)

textme("gm sexy ")
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GGOm.png)

Answer (score 0):

You correctly encode the message in UTF-8, but do not declare it in the email headers. Correctly formatting an email message is hard so you should no try to do it by hand but instead rely on the `email` package.

Here you could do:

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
...
    email_message =  MIMEText(message}
    email_message['To'] = receiver_email
    email_message['From'] = sender_email

    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, smtp_port,
                          context = ssl.create_default_context()) as email:
        email.login(sender_email, email_token)
        email.send_message(email_message)
```

This would will automatically format the message with the appropriate headers, an utf8 charset, and declare the transfer encoding. That way any *normal* mail reader will correcly decode it.

Comment: i added your code in, now it just returns one question mark: 'gm sexy ?', instead of four: 'gm sexy ????' so something's working haha